# PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable

Tags: php, class, variables, parent

```
class A {
    private $aa;
    protected $bb = 'parent bb';
    
    function __construct($arg) {
       //do something..
    }
    
    private function parentmethod($arg2) {
       //do something..
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct($arg) {
        parent::__construct($arg);
    }
    function childfunction() {
        echo parent::$bb; //Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'bb' 
    }
}

$test = new B($some);
$test->childfunction();
```

Question:
How do I display the parent variable in the child?
the expected result will echo 'parent bb'

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```php
echo $this->bb;
```

The variable is inherited and is not private, so it is a part of the current object.

---

Here is additional information in response to your request for more information about using `parent::`:

Use `parent::` when you want *add* extra functionality to a method from the parent class. For example, imagine an `Airplane` class:

```php
class Airplane {
    private $pilot;

    public function __construct( $pilot ) {
        $this->pilot = $pilot;
    }
}
```

Now suppose we want to create a new type of Airplane that also has a navigator. You can extend the __construct() method to add the new functionality, but still make use of the functionality offered by the parent:

```php
class Bomber extends Airplane {
    private $navigator;

    public function __construct( $pilot, $navigator ) {
        $this->navigator = $navigator;

        parent::__construct( $pilot ); // Assigns $pilot to $this->pilot
    }
}
```

In this way, you can follow the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of development but still provide all of the functionality you desire.

Comment: so thats mean **parent** keyword only used to access parent method?

Comment: Usually, you would use parent:: when you want to override a parent method, but still reference the parent's functionality. If you just want to call the parent's method, you do it the same way as for a variable: `$this->parentmethod()`

Answer (score 7):

Just echo it since it's inherited

```
echo $this->bb;
```

Comment: Just make sure that variable is not defined as private.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. The variable is public, but the variables just aren't getting inherited.

Comment: Apparently it's not. I assumed it would be but found they don't get inherited.

Answer (score 6):

With `parent::$bb;` you try to retrieve the static constant defined with the value of `$bb`.

Instead, do:

```
echo $this->bb;
```

**Note:** you don't need to call `parent::_construct` if B is the only class that calls it. Simply don't declare __construct in B class.

Answer (score 4):

$bb has now become the member of class B after extending class A.

So you access `$bb` like it's an attribute of class B.

```
class A {
    private $aa;
    protected $bb = 'parent bb';

    function __construct($arg) {
       //do something..
    }

    private function parentmethod($arg2) {
       //do something..
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct($arg) {
        parent::__construct($arg);
    }
    function childfunction() {
        echo $this->bb; 
    }
}

$test = new B($some);
$test->childfunction();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class A {
    private $aa;
    protected $bb = 'parent bb';

    function __construct($arg) {
       //do something..
    }

    private function parentmethod($arg2) {
       //do something..
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct($arg) {
        parent::__construct($arg);
    }
    function childfunction() {
        echo parent::$this->bb; //works by M
    }
}

$test = new B($some);
$test->childfunction();`
```

Comment: `parent::$this->bb` has got to be the craziest object-oriented syntax I've ever seen

Comment: `parent::` in `parent::$this->bb` achieves nothing but confusing the person asking. I recommend removal or further explanation in order to reduce complexity of the answer.

Comment: this doesn't work `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: A::$this in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/native_testing/index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/native_testing/index.php(29): B->childfunction() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/native_testing/index.php on line 24`

Comment: This code returns `Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: A::$this`

Answer (score 2):

all the properties and methods of the parent class are inherited in the child class so theoretically you can access them in the child class but beware of using the `protected` keyword in your class because it throws a fatal error when used in the child class.
as mentioned in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> The visibility of a property or method
> can be defined by prefixing the
> declaration with the keywords public,
> protected or private. Class members
> declared public can be accessed
> everywhere. Members declared protected
> can be accessed only within the class
> itself and by inherited and parent
> classes. Members declared as private
> may only be accessed by the class that
> defines the member.

Comment: `protected` doesn't throw errors when used in inherited and parent classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP Accessing Parent Class Protected Variable & Methods
class A {
    protected $bb = 'parent bb';
    protected function sayHello(){
        echo 'Say Hello';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function childfunction() {
        echo $this->bb.'<br>'; 
        echo $this->sayHello();
    }
}

$test = new B();
$test->childfunction();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this guide on how to answer questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Through the parent class constructor, you can pass data to the parent class from the child class. Have a look below example for a better understanding

```
<?php

class Student 
{
    public $name;
    function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Test extends Student
{
    public $age;
    function __construct($name,$age){
        $this->age = $age;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }
}

$obj = new Test("sajib khan" ,21);
echo $obj->name;
echo $obj->age;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
class A {
    private $points = 100;

    public function getPoints() {
        return $this->points;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $points = 70;

    public function getPoints() {
        return parent::getPoints();
    }
}

$element = new B();
echo $element->getPoints();
```

change the visibility private or protected for test