# How to extend entity with internal relation?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I hope you will be able to help because I have been searching for a few days now.
I have a class called "Attributes". In it, there is a `parentId` which reference a other entry of `Attributes`.

I want to extend the entity "Attributes" as "Products" with a few extra fields. All the fields are being extended except for the `parentId` relation.

When I add parent to `Products` with getter and setter I get a error:

```
`"Compile Error: Declaration of Products::setParent(?Attributes $parent): Products must be compatible with Attributes::setParent(?Attributes $parent)
  : Attributes"`
```

I have tried a standalone Entity `Products` with all the fields but the relationship to `Attributes` causes database relation issues. And it is an extension of `Attributes`.

Tried different kinds of getters and setters and leaving it out to be extended from the parent.

Have been searching the web for a answer but have not seen inheritance with a internal relationship.

Attributes class:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Attributes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $val;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Attributes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

Products class:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Products extends Attributes
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $newField1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $newField2;
}
```

I would like to know why the internal relationship "Parent" isn't extended and I would love to know how to get the parentId in the extended class.

Comment: Check out the link below for a similar example.
[Similar Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194717/3536236)

Comment: @DavidKariuki Its interesting indeed but I am not using a abstract class to extend because the attributes are also a class that can be called.

Answer (score 2):

Your parent setters seems to be like this:

```
/** Product **/
public function setParent(?Attributes $parent): Products
{
   $this->parent = $parent;

   return $this;
}
/** Attribute **/
public function setParent(?Attributes $parent)
{
   $this->parent = $parent;

   return $this;
}
```

You can fix it simply by replacing `:Products` by `:Attributes`at the end of setParent line in product class.

But you **should** use an interface

```
interface AttributeInterface 
{
    public function setParent(?AttributeInterface $parent): AttributeInterface
}
```

and each of your entity should implement it:

Attribute:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Attributes implements AttributesInterface
{
    /*****/
    public function setParent(?AttributeInterface $parent): AttributeInterface
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Product:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Products extends Attributes implements AttributesInterface
{
   /*****/
}
```

Comment: I tried removing : Products but it still gave the same error. I will try making it with the attributes Interface now.

Comment: I edited my answer, please replace :Products by :Attributes (but it is still a best way to do it with attributes interface.)

Comment: I tried using Attributes and also I just made a interface but the parentId and a other relation doesn't show in the database.