# PHP Get parent class variables from child class constructed in the parent constructor

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

With the following code snippet, why does `$this->foo` return `NULL` in the B child class constructor? From what I've read I was under the impression that a child class inherits all its parent variables and methods

```
$a = new A();

class A {
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = "Hello World";

        $b = new B();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump($this->foo);
    }
}
```

The selected answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable) seems to suggest `$this->foo` should be accessible.

Is it because B is being constructed from within its parent class? If that is the case, how can I access the variable in the child class?

Comment: Can you explain why you need your class to make instances of itself in its constructor? I can't see that being a good idea in any case.

Comment: I don't specifically need the class to make instances of itself, but when the parent class is instantiated I need to instantiate another class to do something else but have access to the variables set in the first class

Comment: You will be able to do that using `parent::__construct()` as long as the class you are making an instance of is not derivative of the one creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `new A()` and then separately you're doing `new B()`. You have two entirely independent object instances. It doesn't matter that one instantiation happens in the constructor of `A`, that's entirely irrelevant. It also doesn't matter that `B` extends `A`. You have two independent objects, and object instances do not share data implicitly, which is what you seem to be expecting.

Since `B`'s constructor overrides its parent's constructor, it's not executing any of `A`'s code either, so essentially nothing is happening when you instantiate a new `B`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a preferred method/best practice to do what I'm trying to do? i.e Set some variables in a parent class, instantiate a child class and access those variables

Comment: *Jein...* Your problem is more likely that you don't know how to apply an object oriented approach to your problem. It's not *impossible* to do what you want, but it's most likely the wrong solution to whatever you're trying to solve there. It's hard to say anything specifically with the generic example you're giving. I'd suggest you post a new question outlining the problem you're trying to solve in OOP.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post a new question considering the down votes this question got but I do appreciate the explanation and now understand why what I was trying to do wasn't working, so I will accept this answer