# Modifying parent public variable in child class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is it somehow possible to modify parent public var which is an array so that in child class it will have more items in it?

For now i'm just repeating parent array physically and then adding some items to it:

```
class A {
    public $arr = ['hello'];
}

class B extends A {
    public $arr = ['hello','world']; //wanna get rid of 'hello' and use parent
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field declaration should be named `$arr`, not `arr`. And, you shouldn't re-declare the same field in the child class. You can change it in the constructor:

```
class A {
    public $arr = ['hello'];
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->arr []= 'world';
    }
}
```

A small test:

```
$a = new A(); print_r( $a->arr );
$b = new B(); print_r( $b->arr );
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
)
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but needs a quick fix.  Missing closing bracket on constructor.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWiley, fixed!

Comment: Thank you. Was writing a comment about $this->arr [] = ['world'], but u've fixed it too already.