# Modifying parent class variable

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I have a same variable in both the classes A and B.

```
class A {
  public $status;
  public function __construct(){}
}

class B extends A {
  public $status;
  public function __construct(){}

 public function modifyParentStatus(){
   /* In the next line i want to change the parent class variable 
     But it changes the current class variable */
    $this->status = 'active';
 }
} 

$obj = new B();
$obj->modifyParentStatus();
```

How can I change parent variable from the child class if both variables has the same name?

I don't want to use extra static functions. I just want to modify it directly.

Comment: There's no parent variable in class `B`

Comment: what do u mean? there is the same variable in parent and child class. I want to change the parent class variable from the child class.

Comment: Is there an actual use case here with code example of where this is not doing what you expect? How are you referencing the class A variable, I don't see that anywhere?

Comment: Writing `public $status;` in B class does not mean that you create another property.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone i have udated the code in the question.

Comment: @u_mulder YES. thats why i am confused. if the name was different then it was straight forward. but in this case it is not.

Comment: You can use Parent:: in a method, example in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable

Comment: @HanzoMiyagi No, i cannot use parent:: because it is used for static members. whereas the variable is not static.

Comment: Why not just use __different__ names?

Comment: remove `public $status;` from child class then try.

Comment: @u_mulder No, the names must be the same.

Comment: @B.Desai It must be in both the class.

Comment: For what purpose they must be the same? Why you complicate your code?

Comment: @u_mulder because I stumbled upon this issue and I want to see if it is possible. It works like a charm when use variables with different names. But I want to do it with the same names

Comment: Good luck then.

Comment: Why do you want to change a parent property? I never ever seen a situation that I have to do something like that. I think it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You probably are looking into changing the property of an object of a parent class from an object of the child class and that would be achieved this way

```
class A {
      public $status;
      public function __construct(){}
      }

class B extends A {
      public $status;
      public function __construct(){}

      public function modifyParentStatus(){
      /* In the next line i want to change the parent class variable 
      But it changes the current class variable */
      //you need to create an instance of the parent class for you to access its properties
      $a = new A();
      $a->status = 'active';
      return $a->status;
     }
} 

$obj = new B();
echo $obj->modifyParentStatus();
```