# Accessing an overloaded PHP property

Tags: php, overloading

I saw some questions about accessing a parent class attribute (like [PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable#6456965)) but I seem to struggle in an edgy case (I actually don't need that pattern, but curiosity, you know...☺):

**What if child class overrides a parent class variable, and still wants to access it?**

Example:

```
class A {
  protected $x = 'a';
}

class B extends A {
  protected $x = 'b';
  public function showX() {
    var_dump(array(
      'this->x' => $this->x,
      'parent->x' => '??',
  }
}

$b = new B();
$b->showX();
```

Without relying on a `getX()` method on parent (and use a `parent::getX()` in the B class or simply a `$this->getX()` if B didn't override that `getX` method), how to get a result like:

```
this->x: 'b'
parent->x: 'a'
```

As http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php#94177 states, using a `parent::$x` won't work, because it would look for the non-existing static attribute `$x`. Any working way?

Comment: Once you've overwritten `parent::$x` ... it's overwritten. Not really any different to procedurally reassigning a variable later in the script - you can't get the original value back.

Comment: You could add a getter for `x` in the parent, then redeclare `A` and use the getter - https://repl.it/M6uV

Comment: What you're trying to do is like giving a variable a value, then overwrite the  value and then you want to get the previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're essentially asking is:

> What if I overrite a value but still want the old value?

Then there is only one simple solution. You make another variable and store it in there before overriting it.

Comment: That was what I thought; but knowing some of PHP stuffs and ways to go... it was worth wondering!