# PHP: How to access overriden public variable

Tags: php

[PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable) -- This question is about accessing parent class variable in child class:

My question is about accessing overridden parent class variable in child class

I am trying to access a overridden public variable, but it's not printing anything.

I am accessing it using

```
echo parent::$var;
```

where the var is a public variable in parent class

```
error_reporting(-1);
class ParentClass{
    public $var='shiva';
/*  public static $var2 = 'arun';
    public function memythod(){
        echo 'mymethod';
    }

    public static function ourmethod(){
        echo 'ourmethod';
    }*/
}


class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public $var = 'shiva1';
    public function __construct(){
        echo $this->var;
        echo "<br>";
        echo parent::$var;
    }

    public function displaymethod(){
        echo $this->var;
        echo parent::$var;
    }


}


$obj = new ChildClass();
$obj->displaymethod();
//$obj->displayvar();
```

Comment: You can't do that. Overridden means overridden. All that's left is `$this->var`.

Comment: If you use class properties instead of instance properties, you can do what you want.

Comment: There are, of course, ways to preserve the data, such as saving the parent value somewhere (say, `$this->parent_var`) before setting `$this->var`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable)

Comment: @vivek modi  that question for accessing the parent class variable in child class. but this question is about accessing overriden variables

Comment: @ Ed Cottrell  is it only for variables, because I can access overriden methods. is there any official references to learn more about this

Comment: @vSugumar will the variable value change for each class instance?

Comment: @fubar yes the variable value in child class is different from parent class variable

Comment: @vSugumar I understand that. But will the value be different for each instance of the child class?

Comment: @fubar no it will be same

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you cannot access the $var from the parent is my point. Once you inherit/extend it, the ChildClass IS the ParentClass -- this is part of the point of the Object-Oriented Principle known as "Liskov Substitution" (SOLID), that you can use a child class interchangably with a parent class. In this case, ChildClass's $var and ParentClass's $var are the same reference. I don't think parent has a separate reference after extension.

For example, say you have a base CAR class and an extending TRUCK class. If you have a $type in each class, you don't really want CAR's $type in TRUCK -- the whole idea is to have a different one. If you want to access the original parent variable, either set a getter or public method for an original value or use a different variable name on the ChildClass/TRUCK class.

For your case, because ChildClass extends ParentClass, anything part of ParentClass should be a part of the THIS context in ChildClass.

You would this access the *$var* like this inside your displayMethod():

```
$this->var
```

[StackOverflow Reference: PHP Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable)

**NOTE**

I edited this answer to be more full following comments and community discussion. Thanks @Ed Cottrel!